# How can I make AR video to always face user's camera with marker vuforia native android

Tags: android, opengl-es, native, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am working on marker AR with native android vuforia what I am trying to do is to move my video object according to camera (it should always face camera) I tried following but its not working but sometime its working but its not persistence

```
public void renderFrame(State state, float[] projectionMatrix) {

        mSampleAppRenderer.renderVideoBackground();
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        isTracking = false;

        for (int tIdx = 0; tIdx < state.getNumTrackableResults(); tIdx++) {
            TrackableResult trackableResult = state.getTrackableResult(tIdx);
            ImageTarget imageTarget = (ImageTarget) trackableResult
                    .getTrackable();
            imageTarget.startExtendedTracking();

            isTracking = true;

            float[] modelViewMatrixVideo = Tool.convertPose2GLMatrix(
                    trackableResult.getPose()).getData();
            float[] modelViewProjectionVideo = new float[16];



            Matrix44F invTranspMV = SampleMath.Matrix44FTranspose(SampleMath.Matrix44FInverse(Tool.convertPose2GLMatrix(trackableResult.getPose())));


            Matrix.translateM(modelViewMatrixVideo, 0, 0f, 0f, 1f);
            Matrix.rotateM(modelViewMatrixVideo, 0, (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(-invTranspMV.getData()[6])), 0.0f, 0.f, 1.0f);


            Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjectionVideo, 0,
                    projectionMatrix, 0, modelViewMatrixVideo, 0);


            GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
            GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            GLES20.glUseProgram(videoPlaybackShaderID);


            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(videoPlaybackVertexHandle, 3,
                    GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, quadVertices);

            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(videoPlaybackTexCoordHandle,
                    2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0,
                    fillBuffer(videoQuadTextureCoordsTransformedStones));

            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(videoPlaybackVertexHandle);
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(videoPlaybackTexCoordHandle);

            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);


            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES,
                    videoPlaybackTextureID);
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(videoPlaybackMVPMatrixHandle, 1,
                    false, modelViewProjectionVideo, 0);

            GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, NUM_QUAD_INDEX,
                    GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, quadIndices);

            GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(videoPlaybackVertexHandle);
            GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(videoPlaybackTexCoordHandle);

            GLES20.glUseProgram(0);
            GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);

            SampleUtils.checkGLError("VideoPlayback renderFrame");
        }

        GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        Renderer.getInstance().end();


    }
```

I have tried above so far and its working sometime but not properly
Please help me i am trying to do this from a week.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to do is to move my video object according to camera (it should always face camera)

If you want that a object faces the camera (Billboarding), then you have to use a model matrix which is the inverse view matrix, but without the translation part.
Use [`Matrix44FInverse`](https://github.com/stenbln/Vuforia-Samples-Android-Studio/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/qualcomm/vuforia/samples/SampleApplication/utils/SampleMath.java), to geht the inverse matrix of a [`Matrix44F`](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/reference/java/classcom_1_1vuforia_1_1Matrix44F.html):

```
public void renderFrame(State state, float[] projectionMatrix) {

    .....

    // get the view matrix and set translation part to (0, 0, 0)
    float[] tempViewMat = Tool.convertPose2GLMatrix(trackableResult.getPose()).getData();
    tempViewMat[12] = 0;
    tempViewMat[13] = 0;
    tempViewMat[14] = 0;

    // create the billboard matrix 
    Matrix44F billboardMatrix = new Matrix44F();
    billboardMatrix.setData(tempViewMat);
    billboardMatrix = SampleMath.Matrix44FInverse(billboardMatrix);

    // calculate the model view projection matrix

    float[] viewMatrixVideo = Tool.convertPose2GLMatrix(trackableResult.getPose()).getData();

    float[] modelViewVideo = new float[16];
    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewVideo, 0, viewMatrixVideo, 0, billboardMatrix.getData(), 0);

    float[] modelViewProjectionVideo = new float[16];
    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjectionVideo, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelViewVideo, 0);

    .....
}
```

---

> I used your code but my AR is rotating in every direction but i want some different thing I have one video that I want to place it vertical on marker and if user move left or right only then i want to rotate it to face camera so that i will see my AR video same that is vertical from any view

What you want to do is to fix the upwards direction, but to orientate the normal vector to the line of sight.

The line of sight is the inverse Z-axis of the view space in a [Right-Handed Coordinate System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule).

```
Matrix44F inverse_view = SampleMath.Matrix44FInverse(
    Tool.convertPose2GLMatrix(trackableResult.getPose()));

// line of sight  
Vec3F los = new Vec3F(-inverse_view[8], -inverse_view[9], -inverse_view[10] );
```

Eiterh the Y-Axis *(0, 1, 0)* or the Z-Axis *(0, 1, 0)* of the model has to be the Z-axis of the orientation matrix.
The X-Axis is the cross product ([`Vec3FCross`](https://github.com/stenbln/Vuforia-Samples-Android-Studio/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/qualcomm/vuforia/samples/SampleApplication/utils/SampleMath.java)) the line of sight and the Z-axis of the orientation matrix.

e.g.

```
Vec3F z_axis = new Vec3F(0, 0, 1);
Vec3F x_axis = Vec3FNormalize(Vec3FCross(los, z_axis));
Vec3F y_axis = Vec3FCross(z_axis, x_axis);
```

```
float[] orientationMatrix = new float[]{
    x_axis.getData()[0], x_axis.getData()[1], x_axis.getData()[2], 0,
    y_axis.getData()[0], y_axis.getData()[1], y_axis.getData()[2], 0,
    z_axis.getData()[0], z_axis.getData()[1], z_axis.getData()[2], 0,
    0,                   0,                   0,                   1
};

// calculate the model view projection matrix

float[] viewMatrixVideo = Tool.convertPose2GLMatrix(trackableResult.getPose()).getData();

float[] modelViewVideo = new float[16];
Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewVideo, 0, viewMatrixVideo, 0, orientationMatrix, 0);

float[] modelViewProjectionVideo = new float[16];
Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjectionVideo, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelViewVideo, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used your code but my AR is rotating in every direction but i want some different thing
I have one video that I want to place it vertical on marker and if user move left or right only then i want to rotate it to face camera so that i will see my AR video same that is vertical from any view.
@Rabbid76

Comment: hey with your new solution my video is rotating in correct directions but on wrong camera movements means when I am rotating my mobile around z axis but I want same rotation when i move my camera around y axis so video will always face camera like a man is always seeing towards camera

Comment: See the video on https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_7fuRizKhqrz9yJLo6ww8xK49xa8gulb

Comment: With Vec3F y_axis = new Vec3F(0, 0, 1); Vec3F x_axis = Vec3FNormalize(Vec3FCross(los, y_axis)); Vec3F z_axis = Vec3FCross(x_axis, y_axis); i cant able to see AR it not coming only audio is there 
@Rabbid76

Comment: @MirzaAhmedBaig And what about the other variant `Vec3F z_axis = new Vec3F(0, 0, 1);` `Vec3F x_axis = Vec3FNormalize(Vec3FCross(los, z_axis));` `Vec3F y_axis = Vec3FCross(z_axis, x_axis);`. By the way, the link does not work: "required permission missing"

Comment: sorry for link but with other variant video is rotating on wrong camera movement

Comment: https://youtu.be/b032rThCseU see this link its working like this with that variant

Comment: any comment @Rabbid76

Comment: @MirzaAhmedBaig Since I can't debug your application, the only thing I can investigate is the video from your link.
One last try before I give up: `Vec3F z_axis = new Vec3F(0, 1, 0);` `Vec3F x_axis = Vec3FNormalize(Vec3FCross(los, z_axis));` `Vec3F y_axis = Vec3FCross(z_axis, x_axis);`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this before but did not work can you plz give me your email address so I can share my BitBucket project?? @Rabbid76